# Re-execute api call when screen size changes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

How do I do this in Backbone Marionette when width of the screen changes, re-execute the fetching? Right now, my code has to be reloaded in order to check the width of the browser.

```
device = getDevice(); // returns desktop or mobile based on $(window).width();

if (device === 'desktop') {
  // let's pull desktop data
  this.desktop = new desktopItemModel({device: 'desktop'});
  this.desktopPromise = this.desktop.fetch();
}

if (device === 'mobile') {
  // let's pull mobile data
  this.mobile = new mobileItemModel({device: 'mobile'});
  this.mobilePromise = this.mobile.fetch();
}

this.allPromise = [desktopPromise, mobilePromise];

if (device === 'desktop') {
    $.when(this.desktopPromise).done(_.bind(function() {
        // do your desktop stuff
    }, this));
}
if (device === 'mobile') {
    $.when(this.mobilePromise).done(_.bind(function() {
        // do your mobile stuff
    }, this));
}
```

Comment: `window.onresize = callFetchFunction;`

Comment: so looks like part of Javascript and not really Backbone right?

Comment: Yes, this is VanillaJS

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I think your code could benefit from some restructuring.

```
var model;

function getData () {
  model = new Model(type: device)
  model.fetch().then(doStuff)
}

function doStuff () {
  if (model.type == 'desktop') {
    // desktop stuff
  } else {
    // mobile stuff
  }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", _.debounce(fetchData, 1000))
// some browsers trigger a lot of resize events, others just at the end
fetchData()
```